# how do i find a bunch of elements after page load and regroup them inside a new div?

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic

So yes, my head hurts. What i aim to achieve:

i have content that is generated dynamically from php inside a page, eg, i use a PHP include to fetch content. Now once this content has loaded, i wish to use javascript/jQuery in order to find certain elements by ID, see if theres more than one, if there is, then group them in a new div.

For example; i have a div named 'pony', the page has 3 other divs, also named 'pony', using javascript/jQuery i wish to house them in a new div named 'horse' which will be generated on the fly. I should also say the new div has to be generated at the top of the page.

But i have a div named 'cows' and there is only one, i want js/jQuery to ignore that one.

Does anyone know how to do this? Rather if PHP would be easier, then id welcome the knowledge of that too.

Comment: It sounds like you have more than one element with the same `id`, which is invalid and will cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: agreed would a class or name be a better option?

Comment: `class` would probably be the best option. jQuery makes it very easy to select by class name (and any attribute really, but I would use class).

Comment: much appreciated, class it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a class to define the previous divs, you can use the $(".pony") selector to have a count of the number of divs generated dynamically, then create a new DOM element called 'horse' and append the previous pony divs to it as such:

```
$(function() {
    var listPony = $(".pony");

    if (listPony.length >= 3)
    {
        var newDiv = $("<div class='horse'></div>").append(listPony);
        $('body').prepend(newDiv);
    }
});
```

Full example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/CPAfA/

Answer (score 2):

Having mutliple elements with same ID is not valid.

However if you cannot avoid it, then try using something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var ponies = $("[id='pony']");
    if(ponies.length > 1){
        $("<div id='horse' ></div>").prependTo("body").append(ponies);
    } 
});
```